# How to parse a Module name canonically

Tags: regex, module, raku, zef

I have a regex that parses a string that should be a fully qualified module name for Raku (see below). Since only the auth, ver, and api versions seem to be used in the Precomp modules, I only test for those.

I need to separate out the name of the module from the identifiers.

My regex is:

```
my $rx := /
                       ^
                       $<name> = ( [ \w | '::' ] + )
                       [ ':' $<part> = ( [ 'ver' | 'auth' | 'api' ] )
                        \< ~ \> $<val> = ( .*? ) ]*
                       $
                      /;
```

Question is whether there is a standard way to match to a Raku module, or a sub so that this regex does not become an error in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [grammar of Raku](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1986), it looks like it is just first eating *all* adverbs in a package definition, and then checks each one of them if it's either `ver`, `auth` or `api`, to `die` if it is not one of these.

So, I would say: No, currently there is no standard way to match a Raku module name.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the best if you use Zef::Identity

```
use Zef::Identity;

say Zef::Identity.new( "WithApi:ver<0.0.2>:api<1>" ).hash;
# {api => 1, auth => , from => Perl6, name => WithApi, ver => 0.0.2}
```

It's probably already installed in your system, since it's part of
[`zef`](https://github.com/ugexe/zef)